# C# Binding Textboxes as parameters in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've started learning MVVM and although I generally understand the theory I'm having trouble understanding how to bind textboxes so that they pass their values as  parameter value for a sqlcommand. My Code:

BookModel Class

```
public class BookModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string bookTitle;
    public string BookTitle
    {
        get { return bookTitle; }
        set { bookTitle = value; OnPropertyChanged(BookTitle); }
    }

    private string bookAuthor;
    public string BookAuthor
    {
        get { return bookAuthor; }
        set { bookAuthor = value; OnPropertyChanged(BookAuthor); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The method in my viewmodel I am passing into my commandclass : ICommand. Thankfully the command runs, so that's fine.

```
    public void AddBook()
    {

        BookModel bk = new BookModel();
        SampleSQL exsql = new SampleSQL();
        exsql.NewBooks(bk.BookTitle, bk.BookAuthor);

    }
```

the samplesql class that contains the SqlCommand I'm running

```
public void NewBooks(string bookTitle, string bookAuthor)
    {
        this.BookTitle = bookTitle;
        this.BookAuthor = bookAuthor;
        string query = "Insert Into BookModel (BookTitle, BookAuthor) Values (@BookTitle, @BookAuthor)";


        SqlConnection ConStr = new SqlConnection(connection);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, ConStr);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookTitle", BookTitle);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookAuthor", BookAuthor);

        using (ConStr)
        {
            ConStr.Open();
            try
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException exception)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
        }
    }
```

The relevant XAML with the datacontext and resources set

```
   <Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>
    <local:BookModel x:Key="bm"/>
</Window.Resources>

   <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Book Title" Style="{StaticResource ItemHeading}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=BookTitle, Source={StaticResource bm}}" Style="{StaticResource LongTB}"/>

 <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Book Author" Style="{StaticResource ItemHeading}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=BookAuthor, Source={StaticResource bm}}"  Style="{StaticResource LongTB}"/>
```

My understanding is that since the textboxes are bound that they should magically pass their values to the viewmodel. However, clearly I'm missing something as I keep running into a sqlexception that tells me that the corresponding parameter in the query is not being supplied (which I'm assuming means its not being passed because there isn't a value).

I'm going to guess that the problem lies with the connection between the AddBook() method in the ViewModel and the view but try as I might I can't seem to crack this one.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The defect is in your AddBook Method.

```
public void AddBook()
{
    // You are creating new instance of BookModel here which is not bound to UI. 
    BookModel bk = new BookModel();
    SampleSQL exsql = new SampleSQL();
    exsql.NewBooks(bk.BookTitle, bk.BookAuthor);
}
```

You should do one of the following.

1. Do not use BookModel as static resource, instead have it as a property in VM and then bind it to UI.
2. Have AddBook method in BookModel so that it can be invoked on the bound data always.